# Using emulator from spring boot test

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-storage-emulator

There is https://github.com/Azure/Azurite as the official emulator from Microsoft is windows platform only.

I have azurite running in a docker container, however I cannot see any properties in the azure storage starter to override the service it connects to.

Does anyone have a work around?